# C# calculate triangle sides with sinus

Tags: math

So what I am trying to do is this.

1.) User enters side "a" of a triangle, and three angles in degrees(alpha, beta, gamma).
2.) The "a" side of the triangle must be greater than 0, and the sum of alpha, betta and gamma must EQUAL 180 degrees.

Then my program converts this to Radians(PI/180*alpha).

Now what I want to do is to calculate the two  other sides of the triangle(b and c) using the sinus theorem:
a/sinalpha=b/sinbeta=c/singamma
source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines

My question is, how do I do this? How do I get the two other sides using the sinus theorem? Also, is there a way for c# to accept degrees?
Like we have
int x;
is there a degree x;
or do we use double?

Here is my code so far:

```
double a;
            const double pi = 3.141592;
            double alpha, beta, gamma;
            Console.WriteLine("Insert alpha:");
            alpha = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Beta");
            beta = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Gama");
            gamma = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("insert side a");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (alpha+beta+gamma==180 || a>0)
            {
                double radianalfa = pi / 180 * alpha;
                double radianbeta = pi / 180 * beta;
                double radiangama = pi / 180 * gamma;

               //How do I calculate the two other sides? (b and c)
                Console.WriteLine(stranicaalfa);
                Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

In the sinus theorem, you have to cross multiply. so It becomes:

sinalpha*b=sinbeta*a
b= sinbeta*a/sinalpha